# How to pass multiple variables from global scope into callback scope?

Tags: php, callback, scope, strpos, stripos

I am trying to use below code to filter JSON data an it works flawlessly if I give filter

```
$search_text = '53';
$filter_name ='title';

$expected88 = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($search_text) {
       return ( stripos($el['title'], $search_text) !== false );
     //      return ( stripos($el[$filter_name], $search_text) !== false );
     
        
    });

echo json_encode($expected88,true);
```

You can see that if I give this `$el['title']` in `stripos()` it works, but if I try to pass `$el[$filter_name]` it does not work.

I tried several other combination like `$el["$filter_name"]`
`$el['.$filter_name.']` but nothing is working -- it's dynamic data that I want to pass variable.

Comment: Seemingly related: [How to pass multiple variables to and from a callback function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56747914/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$filter_name` is not available in anonymous function, so you need to `use` it, same as you do with `$search_text`:

```
$expected88 = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($search_text, $filter_name) {
   return ( stripos($el[$filter_name], $search_text) !== false );
});
```

Comment: In `use` you pass any number of variables that will be available in your anonymous function: `use ($v1, $v2, $v3)` or `use ($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5)`.